# What's the difference between these two types of calling JavaScript anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two types of running a JavaScript function?

```
(function() {
    //Code #1
})();
```

and

```
(function() {
    //Code #2
}());
```

I've seen both of these and i tend to use the #1.

Comment: Same. Douglas Crockford prefers the second one.

Comment: Look, a lot of same working way, with just a difference of bytes: http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/zsAfF/8/ (If you find another way, please tell it to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functional difference at all... just a manner of style.

Answer (score 1):

None -- they are both self-executing anonymous functions which hide variables from the parent namespace.